# orders are not getting updated after payment in ccavenue

Tags: payment-gateway, prestashop, ccavenue

i am using ccavenue in my `prestashop store Version 1.2.5.0`. My problem is after successful credit card transaction, when coming back to website, shopping cart items are not clearing and also orders are not updating. I am using CCavenue Payment Gateway developed by bluezeal.in. In merchant account settings I have given Return Page URL as  `http://myshop /modules/ccavenue/validation.php` where I am updating my order table.  And in ccavenue.php page I have given my return url as `$Url ='http://'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/ccavenue/validation.php'`.  After successful transaction ccavenue is not returning anything to my validation.php page. Ie, `AuthDesc`, `Order_Id` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem got solved after regenerating key in merchant account settings..